# jQuery calculate the number of line breaks in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So I have a `div wrap` whose size is a percentage of the screen width. Inside this `wrap` is multiple `.item divs`. As the window gets smaller it breaks into new lines obviously.

I wrote some code which basically takes the `width` of the `wrap` and divides it by the sum of the widths of the `.item` boxes. But the flaw is that it looks at it thinking how many boxes could fit in total, were one to mix and match them perfectly like building blocks, but that's not how it works because the ordering is stagnant.

How could I make this logic work?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/BradMitchell/pen/KqjpOR)

jQuery:

```
var itemWidth = 0;
var lineCount = 1;


$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var lineWidth = $('.line').width();
  var itemWidthSum = 0;
  lineCount=1;

  $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
      if(itemWidthSum < (lineWidth - $(element).outerWidth())) {
        itemWidthSum = itemWidthSum + $(element).outerWidth();
      } else {
        lineCount++;
        itemWidthSum = 0;
      }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="rect"> 
    <div class="line">
  </div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
</div>


 <h1 class="answer"></h1>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding:25px;
}

.answer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
  height: auto;
  width: 30%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #aef2bd;
  float: left;
}

.rect {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.rect .line {
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Please include [runnable sample code](http://imgur.com/a/sjCS7)

Comment: @AmitKB will do.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my logic mistake by debugging each step.

The correct jQuery:

```
var itemWidth = 0;
var lineCount = 1;


$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var lineWidth = $('.line').width();
  var itemWidthSum = 0;
  var list = [];
  lineCount=1;

  $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
      if((lineWidth - itemWidthSum) > ($(element).outerWidth())) {
        itemWidthSum = itemWidthSum + $(element).outerWidth();
      } else {
        lineCount++;
        itemWidthSum = $(element).outerWidth();
      }
  });
});
```